# GraphicsDeviceManager object from my class (Better explanation in the post)

Tags: c#, xna

Alright, so I have a GameObject class (I made by myself) and I wanted to create a for example GraphicsWidth variable that contains the Maximum width of the screen, it means I need to create a GraphicsDeviceManager instance. (Right?). Alright, this is what I did:

```
protected GraphicsDeviceManager GM;

public int GraphicsWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return GM.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Width;
        }
    }
```

And it says that I need to use the "new"(initialize the object). But I don't know how can I do that from my GameObject class?

Please please please, can anyone help me with this? Really appriciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT:** Anyone please?

Comment: Begging typically does not increase the chances of a response.

Answer (score 0):

The GraphicsDeviceManager is instantiated in your Game1 class. Most likely, you are also instantiating your gameObject in your Game1 class too. When you instantiate your gameObject, pass a reference of the graphicDeviceManager with it:

```
//somewhere in your game1 class:
GameObject gameObject = new GameObjec(Graphics);


//then, in and above the constructor of your GameObject:
GraphicsDeviveManager GM;
public GameObject(GraphicsDeviceManager gdm)
{
   GM = gdm;//GM is now available to the rest of the gameObj class.
}
```

Or... Do the same as above but pass along the Services so you can use anything it contains. 
Or... pass the Game reference along the same way. I see lots of people do that.
Or... Make the graphicsDeviceManager static since there will only be one.

I usually pass the service container ref but most people pass the game ref. Some people pass the reference only to the method in the GameObject class that actually needs it.

Comment: @Joey, it's not about creating a "new" GraphicsDeviceManager. In fact you should only ever have one... It been created automatically by xna in the Game Class. It's about passing a reference to that already existing one to your GameObject class. That's what my post is trying to convey.

Comment: Thanks for your effort with answering, The first line seems to not work properly, I'll explain myself better.

Comment: Alright, so I'm having a GameObject class, and I want this class to have an accsses to the graphics device, so I'll be able to get the Max Screen width for example, so I can use this with another object that I'll create that bounds with the screen borders.